# How to tell if something is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So on my review for my final exam there is this question:

Is there a linear transformation from $P_2$ to $P_2$ with the following properties? In each case, either give an example of such a transformation or prove that no such transformation exist.

> $T(t^2+t+1) = t^2+t+1, T(t^2+2t+3) = 3t^2+2t+1, T(t^2+2t+2) = 2t^2+2t+1$

So we know that the standard basis for $P_2$ is

{$1,t,t^2$}

My question is how do you even start?  Is there a trick? we have never done this kind of question in our class before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\{t^2+t+1, t^2+2t+3,t^2+2t+2\}$ is independent in $P_2$. Thus there exists such liner map $T$ and is unique. Find $T(t^2), T(t)$ and $T(1)$ solving the system
$$T(t^2)+T(t)+T(1)=t^2+t+1\\
T(t^2)+2T(t)+3T(1)=3t^2+2t+1\\
T(t^2)+2T(t)+2T(1)=2t^2+2t+1$$

Comment: I notice that the coefficients of the terms are reverse after the transformation such as: $T(t^2 + 2t+ 3) = 3t^2+2t+1$.  $T$ just reverses the coefficients of $ p(t)$.
That is, $T(at^2 + b^t + c) = ct^2 + bt + a.$ Since this does the job, and is linear, this must be a solution.  Would that be true?

Comment: The coefficients are reversed in these cases. This does not mean that $T(at^2+bt+c)=ct^2+bt+a$ in general. Calculate $T$ to find out if $T(at^2+bt+c)=ct^2+bt+a$ in general.

Answer (score 3):

Are $t^2 + t + 1$, $t^2 + 2 t + 3$, $t^2 + 2 t + 2$ linearly independent?  If so, then they form a basis and there is such a linear transformation.  If not, you must determine whether these equations are consistent.

Comment: I notice that the coefficients of the terms are reverse after the transformation such as: $T(t^2 + 2t+ 3) = 3t^2+2t+1$.  $T$ just reverses the coefficients of $ p(t)$.
That is, $T(at^2 + b^t + c) = ct^2 + bt + a.$ Since this does the job, and is linear, this must be a solution.  Would that be true?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

$T\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&3&2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&2\\1&2&2\\1&3&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&2\\1&2&2\\1&3&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&3&2 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
T = \begin{bmatrix} 0&2&-1\\0&1&0\\1&-2&2 \end{bmatrix}$